# Are there any publications about deanonymizing Bitcoin?

Tags: legal, privacy, government

At the Model United Conference I attend, there is a resolution proposed to de-anonymize BTC in order to cull Darknet transactions.

I know it is impossible but how do i prove it to the other delegates?

Scientific peer-reviewed publications would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good resource is http://arxiv.org/. Search bitcoin in the search bar, and then look for "anon" on the page to find articles about anonymization and de-anonymization in bitcoin.

Doing that, I found these examples:

- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.07782.pdf
- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06160.pdf
- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7418.pdf
- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4524.pdf